# Symbol lookup error while starting pidgin in Arch

Tags: arch-linux, pidgin

I have just installed pidgin from the source code that i downloaded from pidgin site, it compile correctly with using below commands :

`./configure --disable-gtkspell ; make ; make install`

but, when i try to start pidgin from terminal, occurres an error :‌

```
pidgin: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libfarstream-0.1.so.0: undefined symbol: g_key_file_free
```

how can i solve this problem ?

Thanks for your attention :)

Comment: Why haven't you used the Pidgin for the repos or used `abs` to build pidgin using a `PKGBUILD`?

Comment: Looks like the configure script isn't correctly working out the dependencies.  Do you have libfarstream installed?

Comment: Yes, i installed it with using `#pacman -Sy farstream`